# Searching JSON deeply nested Objects with dynamic keys using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a nested JSON that I'd like to search through using lodash. How can I get the root object from `data` if a search term I'm looking for is within certain keys, and with one of the keys being dynamic?

For example, if I have:

```
"data": [
    { 
        "name": "Bob's concourse"
        "activities": [
             {
                 "day": "Monday",
                 "routines":
                     {
                         "Biking": 
                         {
                             "details": "won 3 trophies"
                             "type": "road"
                         },
                         "Kayaking":
                         {
                             "details": "participated in 3 races"
                             "type": "rhythm"
                         }
                      }
                 }
             }
        ]
    },

    {..other_data_etc...},

]
```

- `activities` can be `[]`; it's not guaranteed that it contains any data.
- `routines` keys are dynamic. ie, `Biking`, `Kayaking` are dynamic strings. It can be anything.

If I want to search for an `races` (case insensitive), I want to search specifically in:

- `data.name`
- `data.activities.routines.*` (the dynamic keys)
- `data.activities.routines.*.details`

If any one of those matches, then it will return the root object: `{ "name": "Bob", ..... }`

I was able to get the `name` to return:

```
function searchText(collection, searchterm) {
    return _.filter(collection, function(o) { 
        return _.includes(o.name.toLowerCase(), searchterm)
    } );
};
```

But I'm still new to lodash, and I was unable to get any of the nested searches to return correctly, especially with the dynamic keys part.

Could anyone help explain a solution?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194104/633183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on your existing attempt with lodash:

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
    name: 'Bob\'s concourse',
    activities: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      routines: {
        Biking: {
          details: 'won 3 trophies',
          type: 'road'
        },
        Kayaking: {
          details: 'participated in 3 races',
          type: 'rhythm'
        }
      }
    }]
  }]
};

function search(str, data) {
  const searchStr = str.toLowerCase();

  // Only return the entries that contain a matched value
  return _.filter(data, (datum) => {
    // Check if name matches
    return _.includes(datum.name, searchStr)
    || _.some(datum.activities, (activity) => {
        return _.entries(activity.routines).some(([routine, {details}]) => {
          // Check if dynamic routine matches or details
          return _.includes(routine, searchStr) || _.includes(details, searchStr);
        });
      });
  });
}

console.log(search('foobar', obj.data));
console.log(search('races', obj.data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also accomplish this with plain JavaScript. Using some newish syntax such as [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and newish native methods such as [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) essentially follows the same pattern as using lodash:

```js
const obj = {
  data: [{
    name: 'Bob\'s concourse',
    activities: [{
      day: 'Monday',
      routines: {
        Biking: {
          details: 'won 3 trophies',
          type: 'road'
        },
        Kayaking: {
          details: 'participated in 3 races',
          type: 'rhythm'
        }
      }
    }]
  }]
};

function search(str, data) {
  const regex = RegExp(str, 'i');

  // Only return the entries that contain a matched value
  return data.filter((datum) => {
    // Check if name matches
    return regex.test(datum.name)
    || datum.activities.some((activity) => {
        return Object.entries(activity.routines).some(([routine, {details}]) => {
          // Check if dynamic routine matches or details
          return regex.test(routine) || regex.test(details);
        });
      });
  });
}

console.log(search('foobar', obj.data));
console.log(search('races', obj.data));
```